# Get the first number of an integer

Tags: java, swing, integer

I have the following number: 43215 putted in a textField.
and  i got that number with the following instruction:

`String cardNumber = jTextFieldCardNumber.getText();`

I got a string value, how could I do to get the first number of that string?

**the output should be : "4"**.

Comment: `cardNumber.substring(0, 1)`

Comment: You can use `String#charAt()` or `String#substring`  Both are documented in the JavaDocs for the Java API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your input is a string, you can use charAt which is defined at the String class.
example:

```
    String cardNumber = "43215";
    if (cardNumber != null && cardNumber.length() > 0) {
      char firstChar = cardNumber.charAt(0);
      System.out.println("first char is: " + firstChar);
    } else {
        System.out.println("empty card number");
    }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html